# Redhat - command/s run post-install to generate default localhost.crt?

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I cloned a VM and the ssl certificate has the old hostname. I need to generate a new ssl certificate.

My question is what method was used by the server to create the initial certificate? Was this done as part of the post-install for an RPM? I'll use openssl if there's not a generation script that can be run. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about preserving the current `localhost.crt`, move it from the directory then enter:

```
make testcert
```

in `/etc/pki/tls/certs`

Comment: You should improve your formatting in order to make clear what the command looks like

Answer (score 2):

To answer the OP's question (as opposed to providing methods to generate localhost.crt): it depends on the Linux distribution and version. There are many distributions that use RPM, but I will mention two of the most widely used.

On **CentOS 7/RHEL 7**, it is done in the *postinstall* scriptlet of the `mod_ssl` package. Run the following command to see the full scriptlet:

```sh
rpm -q --scripts mod_ssl
```

The part that actually creates the certificate is this:

```sh
cat << EOF | /usr/bin/openssl req -new -key /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key \
         -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -set_serial $RANDOM -extensions v3_req \
         -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt 2>/dev/null
```

On **Fedora 29**, things are a bit more complicated:

- The *httpd* service (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`) has a soft dependency on *httpd-init.service*.
- *httpd-init.service* (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd-init.service`) is part of the `mod_ssl` package.
- *httpd-init.service* executes `/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-gencerts`, which generates the certificate using `sscg`.

The relevant part of the `/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-gencerts` is this:

```sh
sscg -q                                                             \
     --cert-file           /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt         \
     --cert-key-file       /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key       \
     --ca-file             /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt         \
     --lifetime            365                                      \
     --hostname            $FQDN                                    \
     --email               root@$FQDN
```

The `sscg` tool is a small stand-alone program (not a script). Quoting from the Fedora package description:

> A utility to aid in the creation of more secure "self-signed"
>   certificates. The certificates created by this tool are generated in a
>   way so as to create a CA certificate that can be safely imported into a
>   client machine to trust the service certificate without needing to set
>   up a full PKI environment and without exposing the machine to a risk of
>   false signatures from the service certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly generate a new self-signed certificate and private key using the following command and just follow the prompts.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -nodes -days 3650 -out server.crt
```

One thing I've found enormously useful when I don't care about the attributes of a certificate and just want the hostname to match is that you can pipe attributes into the openssl, just change *test.example.tld* in the command below to match whatever hostname you want to use. It'll leave all of the attributes blank and you'll end up with server.crt and server.key in your current directory:

```
echo -e "XX\n\n \n \n\ntest.example.tld\n\n" | openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -nodes -days 3650 -out server.crt &> /dev/null
```